# Are modern jquery selectors backwards compatible?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

So I know how to use javascript, and have just started trying to learn jquery. When you select an element with `$('css-selecor')`, I'm just wondering about which selectors can be used. I want to use something like `:nth-child(n)`, which is a CSS3 selector. Now my question is, does the user's browser have to be compatible with CSS3 for that to work, or is jquery built to use those selectors to locate the element regardless of the browser?

I am using jquery 1.9.1

Comment: jQuery's selector engine ([Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/)) is completely independent of CSS, it just follows the same pattern to make it easier for developers to use.

Comment: Check the api docs for the [`:nth-child()`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector. It was added in version 1.1.4 which was long before CSS3. It probably tries to use the selector in `document.querySelector` and if it can't, falls back to the [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) engine built into jQuery.

Comment: @War10ck: What do you mean, ["long before"](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/WD-CSS3-selectors-19990803)? ;) I know you probably meant long before it was implemented in browsers or the spec became a REC, but note that it says jQuery derived it from the CSS3 spec - so rather than pre-date it, jQuery was really the first implementation *of* `:nth-child()` as specified in CSS3.

Comment: Some of jQuery's own creations have been ported to Selectors 4 however, for example the subject indicator was just recently replaced with `:has()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery ships with its own [selector engine](http://sizzlejs.com/). If the browser doesn't natively support CSS3 selectors, it falls back to using its own.

You can safely use any CSS3 selector you want and it'll magically work everywhere. No extra work needed on your end.

Answer (score 3):

From the [jQuery Docs](http://jquery.com/browser-support/):

> Regardless of a browser's support of CSS selectors, all selectors
>   listed at api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ will return the correct
>   set of elements when passed as an argument of the jQuery function.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery uses Sizzle (https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Documentation) which pretty much makes sure all CSS selectors will work cross browser, i.e jQuery will ensure cross-browser compatibility of any selectors you use.